# Color arrangements within Circles

Tags: probability

If I had 4 circles A, B, C, and D(See diagram below), how many ways can I arrange three colours that are designated to each one, given that the colour circle C cannot be the same as any other circle? Yes, colours can be repeated. *e.g. Circle A can have the same colour as circle B.*

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Geu.jpg)

I tried to solve this thinking that circle C can have 3 colour choices and every circle after will only have 2 choices. Thus

$$3*2*2*2=24$$

I was wondering if there was a way to make this calculation more compact. Perhaps since this is a permutation problem
$$4nPr3=24$$
This gives me the right numbers(I think by coincidence), but it makes little intuitive sense to me in this context, considering that this does not account for the rule that circle C cannot be the same colour as the others.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your first method would be correct ... *If* the circles are all distinguishable ... which would mean the diagram serves no function at alll ... which is weird ... so maybe we are dealing with a *graph* coloring, in which case A and B are indistinguishable?

If that's the case, then you get efwer than 24 colorings as, for example, coloring A with color 1 and coloring B with color 2 would be considerd the same coloring as coloring A with color 2 and B with 1.

Specifically, you get 3 possible colors for C, 2 for D, and 3 possible colorings for A and B: they either both have the same color (2 potions), or have different colors (1 option). This gives a total of $3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3=18$ possible colorings